# Get current machine's HW info and send it to server

Tags: javascript, java, php

I am looking for a solution where I could gather all hardware information of the machine and send these information to PHP server, where it would be processed further.

The usecase would be something like this: there is a new machine in my office, I will run some script / visit an URL and all the machine specific data such as CPU, RAM, SSD, OS etc. would be saved in database.

I checked https://clientjs.org/ but the level of details it provides is not enough. So it probably needs to be in different language than javascript (java?). Also it should be executable on windows, linux and macOS.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: No browser, and consequently javascript solution, will have access to the OS information your looking for.

Comment: @enjoylife See [adzerk serving ads from adsafeprotected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335956/)

Comment: yeah I figured, doesnt have to be browser solution.

Comment: Just found [some tutorial on electron framework](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/108/how-to-get-operative-system-and-hardware-information-with-electron-framework) while googling for "framework for on windows, linux and macOS getting hardware information"